# EWMA: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r, time-series, summary

I am running the Exponentially Weighted Moving Average (EWMA) function on my data. I tried storing the summary statistics in a variable so that I could write it to a text file. But, this is the error that I get:

```
> library(qcc)
> q <-  ewma(x$var1, lambda=0.2, nsigmas=2.7)
> s <- summary(q)
Error in object[[i]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi How do I generate summary statistics for that? My dataset is too big to be plotted. I need the summary statistics.

Comment: what does var1 looks like in your dataframe x?

Comment: @edouard typeof(var1) is integer. When I run the EWMA function, it also says: Error: cannot allocate vector of size 33.1 Gb. How do I get past this?

Comment: you need to use specific functions such as the ones in ff or bigmemory to deal with such amount of data